Add Linux server to AD without entering password
When I run command:
realm join -U adminuser@PORTON.COM.IL porton.com.il --verbose 

I am prompted to enter the password for adminuser@PORTON.COM.IL. Since I want to run this in a script for a lot of servers, Is there a way to skip this prompt or automatically send the password from the script (Its script running in bash or csh).

One possible way is to use command like this:
echo <password> |realm join -U adminuser@PORTON.COM.IL porton.com.il --verbose 

I know it is not secure but this work for me. You should take care to wrap password so if there are special symbols they will not be interpreted by shell.

expect sounds what you might use to script it.
Password handling is also a topic there:

It is often useful to store passwords (or other private information)
in Expect scripts. This is not recommended since anything that is
stored on a computer is susceptible to being accessed by anyone. Thus,
interactively prompting for passwords from a script is a smarter idea
than embedding them literally. Nonetheless, sometimes such embedding
is the only possibility.

Actually, the issue with supplying input to a script was already solved here at U&L StackExchange.
